# Issue with connecting ELM327 bluetooth adapter to raspberry pi, Bullseye latest OS

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to read OBD data from ELM327 BT Adapter. I have paired it successfully, and bind using rfcomm is also OK. However, while running the obd python module I am getting the following error:

```
>>> connection = obd.Async("/dev/rfcomm99", protocol="6", baudrate="38400", fast=False, timeout = 60)
[obd.obd] ======================= python-OBD (v0.7.1) =======================
[obd.obd] Explicit port defined
[obd.elm327] Initializing ELM327: PORT=/dev/rfcomm99 BAUD=38400 PROTOCOL=6
[obd.elm327] write: b'ATZ\r'
[obd.elm327] wait: 1 seconds
[obd.elm327] Device disconnected while reading
[obd.elm327] cannot perform __write() when unconnected
[obd.elm327] cannot perform __read() when unconnected
[obd.elm327] ATE0 did not return 'OK'
[obd.obd] Closing connection
[obd.obd] Cannot load commands: No connection to car
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
>>> print(obd.scan_serial())
['/dev/rfcomm99']
```

Can Someone help? I have tried other baud rates, the issue still is the same. I am using this adapter: https://www.amazon.in/Generic-Bluetooth-Adapter-Scanner-Diagnostic/dp/B06X1H18WK. Really need to debug this issue asap.

Comment: You could try running `sudo btmon` at the same time in another terminal to see if it gives any clues as to why the device is disconnecting. `rfcomm`  was [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617)  in 2017 so the current way of doing things will break at some point. I think using a Python socket client would probably be the current was of doing this but would require a change to the obd python module. Example client socket at https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/